# ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'raw')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to display post content data from an API. I can see all data in console but can't print on page. Body data has text, images and links.

```
    {
    _createdAt: '2022-07-12T20:34:38Z',
    _id: 'bd2c8b42-dafc-4790-a2b4-58f26eaffc61',
    _rev: '7YXCB5lEK7kKTPSVqfqJAU',
    _type: 'post',
    _updatedAt: '2022-08-04T00:04:03Z',
    author: { _ref: 'a0ede624-53aa-47c8-8b46-0cc26fdccdb2', _type: 'reference' },
    body: [
        {
        _key: '19eb74b79eea',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: '72c060bc0b85',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        { _key: '5ed0ee0d220b', _type: 'image', asset: [Object] },
        {
        _key: 'c4a2b577f8ca',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: 'ed759595ca4d',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        level: 1,
        listItem: 'bullet',
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: '9a9039e54e61',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        level: 1,
        listItem: 'bullet',
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: '3abb66409433',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        level: 1,
        listItem: 'bullet',
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: 'e75487026e41',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: '9e1d2e4a7bb8',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: 'fbe3a225084c',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: 'd00b4b88aad2',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: '4e58b30c2ebb',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        },
        {
        _key: 'ca9bdd4a4350',
        _type: 'block',
        children: [Array],
        markDefs: [],
        style: 'normal'
        }
    ],
    categories: [
        {
        _key: '9cf008956dfe',
        _ref: 'f1f6d065-6720-4f3a-b462-f5c1e86829d4',
        _type: 'reference'
        }
    ],
    excerpt: 'some excerpts',
    featuredImage: [ { _key: '823231ffcf7b', _type: 'image', asset: [Object] } ],
    featuredPost: true,
    slug: { _type: 'slug', current: 'post-1' },
    title: 'Post Title'
    }
```

I can get Title and Date but when I need to display nested objects like Body, Author or Category, I receive an error.

My fetching function is like this

```
    const PostDetail = ({ post }) => {
        const getContentFragment = (index, text, obj, type) => {
        let modifiedText = text;
    
        if (obj) {
            if (obj.bold) {
            modifiedText = (<b key={index}>{text}</b>);
            }
    
            if (obj.italic) {
            modifiedText = (<em key={index}>{text}</em>);
            }
    
            if (obj.underline) {
            modifiedText = (<u key={index}>{text}</u>);
            }
        }
        };
```

But it gives me an error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
```

Printing title like this is fine

```
    {post.title}
```

But for body below code is not working

```
    {post.body.raw.children.map((typeObj, index) => {
       const children = typeObj.children.map((item, itemindex) => 
           getContentFragment(itemindex, item.text, item));
                return getContentFragment(index, children, typeObj, typeObj.type);
          })}
```

Comment: I do not see a key of "content" in your post object

Comment: @Sean typo fixed

Comment: body is an array not an object. you have to loop through body, the .raw syntax will not work

Comment: @Sean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: Need to map over body like `post.body.map` since body is an array. You'd still need to map `children` like you're already doing.

Comment: I was able to print content like this`{post.body.map((typeObj, index) => {const children = typeObj.children?.map(...` But without formatting and images. I need to print it pretty with html tags and image.

Comment: I found [this package](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext) for rendering but seems very complex.